# Is Admob still get banned in iOS

Tags: ios, admob

I'm developing my iOS and android app and having trouble with iAd network is working only in some country so i will use admob but I found a news about admob get banned in iOS in 2010.
and there is no recent news about this anymore.

But I found someone in the internet use admob for iOS app. and somebody still recommended to use iAd instread of admob.

Anyone can confirm that Admob is now allow for iOS or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were banned, Google wouldn't offer it on the [AdMob signup and download page](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/).

(plus Apple would have a lot of explaining to do to the U.S. Federal Trade Commission)

I'm guessing your query [comes from this TechRadar story](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/computing/apple/admob-hits-back-at-apple-ban-695483), but when you go to the AdMob download page, it specifies that UDID is being used for iOS 5 and a newer "advertising identifier" (IDFA) is being used for iOS 6 and newer.